# Why cannot I delete a Lotus Notes document?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

in my Lotus Notes agent, I temporarily created some documents using a new form (with a richtext field in the form), and in the end of the code, I have "Call TempDoc.Remove(True)", when the program execute this line of code, I got error "Notes error: No documents were deleted", then I commented out this code to let the document saved in the current database, so I manually delete those documents created by my program by click Delete key, but I got the same error "No documents were deleted", I have Manager access with delete option in the database ACL,

Does anybody know why I got that error?

By the way, if I created a new document by using the default form which is not the form used in my program above, then I can delete it.

So, the question may be: what kinds of documents created in the notes database can NOT be deleted by a id with Manager and Delete option?

Comment: Do you have any code in the QueryDocumentDelete event in the Database Scripts?

Comment: No, I checked it, no codes in Database script library.

Comment: I checked the codes again, the tempdoc did saved, but it was saved as MIME type, and the ContentType = "multipart", no sure if this caused the problem, any idea?

Comment: the Form name is assigned properly, I also can see the Form name item from the document property. The form is very simple, only has one richtext "Body" field in it. 
Restart notes client does not fix the problem. 
Only documents created by my agent code have this issue.
Querydocumentdelete script library is clean, nothing there.
can not find anywhere else.
But one thing I can tell is: in my codes, before saving the tempdoc, I set
session.ConverMime = True, no sure it this cases the problem.

Comment: If my answer below doesn't do the trick... I really don't think MIME content enters into it. My next step would be to manually create a doc using the same form and see if you can delete it.  Since you say there are no other fields in the document, that rules out my next thought that you're blocked by a reader names field.  So my next step would be to suggest copying the document and pasting it into an empty NSF, and then trying to delete it from that NSF.  That will help you narrow it down to whether it's something specific to the doc, or something specific to your original database.

Answer (score 4):

The `NotesDocument.Remove(true)` method may be trying to do a "soft deletion", but the database may not be [properly set up](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21091152) for soft deletes. If you don't care about soft deletes, then try the `NotesDatabase.RemovePermanently(true)` method instead.